myCred WordPress Plugin Custom Column Export
I am using the myCRED plugin as part of a WordPress project I am working on.
I have successfully added a custom column “Team Name” to the admin Points Log table. Both the column header and data show there. I am attempting to add that new column to the csv file on export. I am having a hard time getting it to work. The “Team Name” column header shows up in the csv export, but the column data does not. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here are the functions I created to add this column to the Log table.
// Add custom log column header
add_filter( 'mycred_log_column_headers', 'mycredpro_add_log_column' );
function mycredpro_add_log_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['team-name'] = 'Team Name';
    return $columns;
}

// Add custom log column data
add_filter( 'mycred_log_team-name', 'mycredpro_add_log_column_content', 10, 2 );
function mycredpro_add_log_column_content( $content, $entry ) {
    $user_id = $entry->user_id;
    $team_name = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_team_name', true );
    return $team_name ? $team_name : '-';
}

// Add custom log column header to export
add_filter( 'mycred_export_headers', 'my_custom_log_column_header' );
function my_custom_log_column_header( $headers ) {
    $headers['team-name'] = 'Team Name';
    return $headers;
}

Thanks!
